# Find the volume of the parallelepiped with a vertex at the origin, and given 3 vectors parallel to its edges

Tags: linear-algebra, volume, cross-product

So I need to find the volume of the following parallelepiped

It's vertex or apex is the origin so that's (0, 0, 0)

and the three following vectors are parallel to 3 of its edges

- u = (1, -2, 3)
- v = (1, 3, 1)
- w = (2, 1, 2)

I know that the volume is calculated by doing a cross product and a dot product, my teacher calls it a mixte product. However, that apex of (0,0,0) is really throwing me off.

I don't really get what It's given for?